# Is there a name for non-OOP version of 'property'?

Tags: c++

AFAIK In C++, we call the getter/setter function as 'property'.
The getter/setter is used to get/set a member variable.
One of the advantages of doing this is that we can listen for change, like this:

```
// In header:
class XXX {
    int m_width{};

    void OnWidthChanged() {
    // do something...
    }

public:
    int Width() const {
        return m_width;
    }
    void Width(int val)
        m_width = val;
        this->OnWidthChanged();
    }
};
// In CPP:
XXX my_xxx;
my_xxx.Width(123);
cout << my_xxx.Width() << endl;
```

Now I found static variable can be used to implement similar thing, <strike>in a non-OOP fashion</strike> I know it cannot handle multiple-instance, so let's just assume XXX is an object that has only 1 instance.

```
// In header:
int XXX_Width(bool set = false, int val = 0);
void XXX_OnWidthChanged();
// In CPP:
int XXX_Width(bool set, int val) {
    static int width = 0;
    if (set) {
        width = val;
        XXX_OnWidthChanged();
    }
    return width;
}

XXX_Width(true, 123);
cout << XXX_Width() << endl;
```

My question is, is there **a name or term for**  <strike>this kind of functions</strike>  **functions like `XXX_Width()`**?
I'm looking for a name so I can google search for related information.
I'm *not* asking for name for `OnWidthChanged()`.

Comment: Getter\Setter isn't C++ style I think.

Comment: Note that your static-variable-approach is significantly different because it does not work in situations where you would have at least two instances of `XXX`.

Comment: You may find relevant information with "Singleton pattern", "Singleton antipattern" and "Observer pattern"

Comment: AFAIK In C++, we call the getter/setter function as 'property'. ... No we do not. :)

Comment: It is called Callback ....

Comment: @knivil Indeed, contrast c#, where a property is a shared identifier for a (pair of) unnamed get and/or set member functions, or delphi where a property is a name by which you can access named member functions or fields (of the appropriate type), or java where by convention a getFoo() setFoo() pair can be called a property Foo (but this isn't a language element)

Comment: @Caleth A "property" in Delphi/C++ Builder (among other rad tools) only refers to member variables, not functions. I guess the key here is that "property" is not a formally defined term.

Comment: @Lundin properties are a language element of delphi see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Properties#Property_Access

Comment: @Caleth Which is just a fancy fluff way of saying public member variables that can have certain restricted values.

Comment: @yeputons Yes I know it will not work for multiple-instances situation, I've googled the term you gave, it is not what I wanted however. :( I've reworded my question, hope it will be more clear about what I'm looking for this time...

Answer (score 3):

Lots of confusion about terminology here.

OOP simply means that you have autonomous classes with their functionality encapsulated. Both your examples use OO, though if they are bad or good design is another matter.

> > Now I found static variable can be used to implement similar thing, in a non-OOP fashion:

There is nothing non-OOP with your example. It is however probably bad OO design, since multiple instances of your class may access that same function. It is also bad design from a thread-safety perspective.

Sometimes, using static variables locally is perfectly fine though, like for example when implementing "singleton" classes.

> In C++, we call the getter/setter function as 'property'

No, that is not a common term. Getter/setter functions are called members, or member functions. Or possibly public member functions, since by definition those must be public. Another term used for them is *methods*.

The term property is most often used to describe public member *variables*. Often RAD tools use the term property for such variables.

> My question is, is there a name or term for this kind of functions?

A function which is specified by the caller, but called by someone else (the class, the OS, an interrupt etc) is universally called *callback function*. This is a fairly broad term.

In your case, you seem to use callback functions like "events" - an event is a kind of callback function but a higher level concept. Code like your example could be used for so-called "event-driven design", which is also popular among RAD tools.

Comment: I'm not sure about the property, but I think you misunderstood my question. I was asking for name/term of `XXX_Width()`, which behaves like getter/setter but not inside a class, and it is intentionally not for multiple-instances neither, the XXX it modifies is single-instance only.

Comment: @raymai97 It's just a plain function. It is not part of any particular well-known design pattern. Probably because it is a rather bad design...

Answer (score 1):

The 1<sup>st</sup> point that should be made is that your "property block" or "getter/setter" are non-conformant. [The expected declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#C.2B.2B_example) look like:

```
int Width() const;
void Width(const int);
```

So when you change the setter to: `XXX& Width(int)` it becomes clear that you aren't talking about "property blocks" or "getter/setters". So let's talk about what your setter does look like:

1. It makes a call *after* `width` changes. Such a call would typically be an [**interupt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) or a [**signal**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)
2. It returns a non-`const` reference to the object. This is the behavior of an [**operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) which notably *do* have outside class versions

Now let's talk about your function: `int XXX_Width(bool set = false, int val = 0)` You've set it up with [**default arguments**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument) such that it could behave as either the setter or the getter in your example, notwithstanding the weirdness of your getter's return.

Given the distinction between the 2 options you present, you seem to be asking:

## Is there a name for using a functions `static` variable instead of defining a function and providing getter/setters for a member variable?

A function scoped `static` variable is called a [**`static` local variable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable#Static_local_variables).

One word of wisdom on `static` local variables:

> A static local variable is different from a local variable as a static local variable is initialized only once no matter how many times the function in which it resides is called and its value is retained and accessible through many calls to the function in which it is declared <sup>[[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable#Scope)]</sup>

Comment: `XXX& Width(int)` would be a "fluent setter", as you could chain a bunch of calls to similarly defined members like `xxx.Width(10).Height(5).Color().oops_no_argument(now_im_calling_some_other_type)`

Comment: @Caleth I've never heard that term, but I could see the same thing being being accomplished by `XXX_Width`. So perhaps that is the term being sought?

Comment: Thanks for answering, however 'static local variable' is not what I'm looking for. What I like to know is the term we use for function like `XXX_Width()`, which behaves like getter/setter but not inside a class.

Comment: @raymai97 Defining a `static` local variable is a common practice in Object Oriented C [sic], in order to simulate member variables or properties. But even in such a case where such a concept is common, it is simply referred to as a `static` local variable. I believe that this is as close as you're going to get to what you're looking for. So I would say: **There isn't a closer term to answer my understanding of your question.**